# CSS files not compiled into app.css as expected in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember CLI docs says about `/app/styles` folder following:

Contains your stylesheets, whether SASS, LESS, Stylus, Compass, or plain CSS (though only one type is allowed, see Asset Compilation). These are all compiled into app.css.

I have the following files in `/app/styles`: `app.css`, `one.css`, `two.css`.

I would expect when starting server that in folder /dist/assets there will be file called `appName.css` and the content would be concatenation of all three files. Instead there is only content of app.css file. So I resolved this with `@import` in app.css:

```
@import url("one.css");
@import url("two.css");
```

That worked with 0.0.46, although not optimal because of more request were made to server. Now I updated to 0.1.1 and files `one.css` and `two.css` are no longer copied to `/dist/assets` folder.

But main question is: How can I achieve the concatenation of all css files in `/app/styles` folder? Am I missing something basic or are there some commands needed to be included into `Brocfile.js`?

**Updated**

Here is the snippet of `Brocfile.js` showing how we concatenate our CSS files:

```
var concat = require('broccoli-concat');
var cleanCSS = require('broccoli-clean-css');

var concatenatedCss = concat('app/styles', {
    inputFiles: [
        'reset.css',
        'common.css',
        'layout.css',
        ...
    ],
    outputFile: '/assets/appName.css',
    wrapInFunction: false
});

if (app.env === 'production') {
    concatenatedCss = cleanCSS(concatenatedCss, {restructuring: false});
}

module.exports = app.toTree([concatenatedCss]);
```

We manually add files to inputFiles array.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @stephanav. Did you manage to get the resulting CSS file fingerprinted and used in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known issue with 0.1.1 version: [Static css compiler broken (0.1.x regression)](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2215)

You probably should wait for update.

As for main question, try [broccoli-concat](https://github.com/rlivsey/broccoli-concat).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Broccoli-concat did what I wanted.

Comment: @stepanhav - I have the same problem. Could you share how you went about that?

Answer (score 0):

Now there is this `ember-cli-concat` add-on available: https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-cli-concat.

Looks super easy to use: https://github.com/sir-dunxalot/ember-cli-concat/wiki/Installation